# sharing $scope between controller and factory in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-factory

I have a variable 'file' that is being passed to a directive which i am using in the same controller. Now i want to use that same 'file' in the factory that i am creating but i'm not sure if there is an easy way to share that same variable between controller and factory.

for example...

fileCategory.directive.js:

```
.directive('fileCategory', function () {
      return {
        templateUrl: '...'
        restrict: 'EA',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
          file: '='
        },
        controller: 'fileCategoryController'
      };
    });
```

fileCategory.controller.js:

```
.controller('fileCategoryController', function($scope) {

      if(!$scope.file) {
        return;
      } else {
        console.log($scope.file);        
      }
```

fileCategory.factory.js

```
.factory('fileCategoryList', function () {

  categories.get = function() {
    if($scope.file){
      return this.categories;
    } else{
      return;
    }
  };
```

I want to be able to use $scope.file in my factory like so...

Comment: use `$rootScope`

Comment: do you mind providing me an example? not too familiar with how to use $rootScope

Comment: same code what you are using, inject `$rootScope` and check.

Comment: awesome!! worked just like that...thx for the help

Comment: No problem, happy coding :)

Comment: @Bharadwaj that is just promoting a bad practice that shouldn't be used

Comment: @charlietfl `$rootScope` is there for this purpose.

Comment: @Bharadwaj no it is not and using it as a data store is a well recognized poor practice

Comment: @charlietfl ya, factories should be used. But for small data `$rootScope` will do.

Comment: @Bharadwaj why is promoting lazy hacks acceptable? That isn't what SO is all about

Comment: @charlietfl this is not bad practice, this is something technically legal. Besides using rootscope is not banned anywhere.There is a possibility to use.That's why I commented. Coming to promoting, did I insisted the user that he have to use rootscope? There is a lot of space to answer, type your own

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using $rootScope is possible here, but please don't use it in this case. Better practice is use service for storing data, and manipulate between different components. When your application will grow, it can be problem store more data in global $rootScope.

```
.service('CategoryService', function () {
 this.file = ...
  }
```

then implement service to controller, factory or anywhere you need

```
.controller('fileCategoryController', function($scope, CategoryService ) {
      $scope.file = CategoryService.file

      if(!CategoryService.file) {
        return;
      } else {
        console.log($scope.file);        
      }
```